# Can't handle jQuery form event

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to handle when an input field is out of focus but I can't get the following to work :

```
jQuery("input").focusout(function() {
    alert('yo');
});
```

Notes :

1. It doesn't work for any of the form events (`blur()`, `change()`, `focus()`, etc.)
2. It works when I replace `"input"` by `document` but it's not what I want to do.
3. I'm using Wordpress so I'm adding the javascript code the normal way like so :

   ```
   function add_scripts() {
       wp_register_script('MyScript', 'script.js', array('jquery'), true);
       wp_enqueue_script('MyScript');
   }
   ```

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: Are you using this inside $(function(){}); in your script file?

Comment: @bhelmet Nope, the console is clear as water.

Comment: What's `content`? Have you tried disabling your plugins or changing themes to see if it works?

Comment: @Cruiser No, should I ? What do you mean exactly ?

Comment: @j08691 I'm using the function in a child theme so I can't change. I don't know if it is good practice, I didn't find anything on the subject. It's `document` not `content`, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, it appeared that I didn't include my function inside ready function `$(function(){});` which seems to be mandatory in jQuery if we want to reach all the elements in the page.

Comment: Strange, the `true` value in `wp_register_script` should've loaded your code into the footer of the page, after all the other elements have been loaded.